# Set maximum download speed in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm using WCF for downloading audio data from database. I need to set maximum download speed.

How can it be done in WCF?

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

WCF handles throttling through the [ServiceThrottlingBehavior](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.servicemodel.description.servicethrottlingbehavior.aspx) class.

[How to throttle a Wcf service](http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/02/20/how-to-throttle-a-wcf-service-help-prevent-dos-attacks-and-maintain-wcf-scalability/)

> WCF provides a throttling behavior to
>   manage server load and resource
>   consumption (with the following
>   properties):
>
> - MaxConcurrentCalls. Limits the number of concurrent requests that can
>     be processed by all service instances.
>     The default value is 16.
> - MaxConcurrentInstances. Limits the number of service instances that can
>     be allocated at a given time. For
>     PerCall services, this setting matches
>     the number of concurrent calls. For
>     PerSession services, this setting
>     matches the number of active session
>     instances. This setting doesn t matter
>     for Single instancing mode, because
>     only one instance is ever created. The
>     default value for this setting is
>     2,147,483,647.
> - MaxConcurrentSessions. Limits the number of active sessions allowed for
>     the service. This includes application
>     sessions, transport sessions (for TCP
>     and named pipes, for example),
>     reliable sessions, and secure
>     sessions. The default value is 10.

I don't think there is a built-in mechanism to control bandwidth.  You would need to implement a custom stream. You use a thread to write the the stream. You can then control how much data to write each second. For example, you could write 250Kb, and then perform a thread sleep for one second.

See also: [Concurrency and Throttling Configurations for WCF Services](http://www.devproconnections.com/article/net-framework2/concurrency-and-throttling-configurations-for-wcf-services)

Answer (score 7):

Ok, insane late-friday shot in the dark:
Scott Gu blogged about a new bit-rate throttling module for IIS 7 Here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/03/18/iis-7-0-bit-rate-throttling-module-released.aspx

It's actually intended for media files, but out of the box, it's triggered by the extension.  By itself, this may not be enough -- you are serving the files from a service -- .svc, and you probably don't want to throttle all of your service calls. (if you don't mind throttling them all, it might work out of the box -- just set a rule on .svc.

What's more interesting though, is this post: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/149/bit-rate-throttling-extensibility-walkthrough/  This guy talks about how to customize the throttler.

You can do it based on response content (he has examples of reading the bit-rate inside of a media file).

Or, about 3/4 of the way down the article, look for this heading: "Setting the Server Variables Programmatically"

He describes how to build an http module/handler -- you could theoretically use that to trigger IIS's throttling based upon a URL (like the url to your media server service)

Never tried this -- total WAG before I go home for the weekend.  Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you take a look at this simple project here: [Simulating Latency and Bandwidth Restrictions in WCF](http://www.milestonetg.com/content/development/36-simulating-latency-and-bandwidth-restrictions-in-wcf.html). It introduces a WCF client behavior capable of increasing network latency.